# Share common configuration between different plugins in the same Maven module

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

I'm working on a Maven project which uses both the Surefire and Failsafe plugins in the same module. The configurations for both plugins are pretty much identical, except for one element (`classpathDependencyExcludes`), as you can see.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
    <configuration>
        <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
        <forkCount>1</forkCount>
        <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
        <argLine>-javaagent:"${project.build.directory}/openejb-javaagent-${tomee.version}.jar"</argLine>
        <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}</workingDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
    <configuration>
        <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
        <forkCount>1</forkCount>
        <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
        <argLine>-javaagent:"${project.build.directory}/openejb-javaagent-${tomee.version}.jar"</argLine>
        <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}</workingDirectory>
        <classpathDependencyExcludes>
            <classpathDependencyExclude>javax:javaee-api</classpathDependencyExclude>
        </classpathDependencyExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I was wondering if there was a way to share the common section of the configuration between the two plugins by writing it down once instead of multiple times. If not, in the hypothesis that both configurations were identical, would it be possible?

Comment: Not able to find a way to do it. You could externalize all the properties, but the configuration object itself is a contained property for a plugin. I will dig more.. worst case, you have an opportunity to write a plugin :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to set all the properties explicitly. `skipTests` has already the value of `${skipTests}`, no need to repeat that. `forkCount` has already the default value 1.

Some of the other properties can be set in the `<properties>` section, like `reuseForks` and `argLine`.

Then there is very little left to worry about.